# php function to return next/previous item in list

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that loads three different pages: a user's followers, following, and their friends (represented below by a, b, and c). Each "page" has different privacy settings depending on who's viewing the website, so a, b, and c have true/false values. If the value is false, then that user cannot view the page. I want to create next and previous buttons, but in order to determine which page is next/previous, I need to factor in the user's privacy. For example, if the user only shows b, there would be no next/previous, but if they showed a, and c, then next/previous for a would be c, and for c it would be a. I wrote some code below that tries to accomplish this, but is there a simpler way to do this without being so repetitious? It's also important that it loop, so even if I'm on page c, the next button will bring me to page a.

```
$a = $_GET['a'];  // true/false
$b = $_GET['b'];  // true/false
$c = $_GET['c'];  // true/false

$cur = // current page: a, b, or c

if($cur = $a) {
    if($b) {
        $next = $b;
    }
    else if($c) {
        $next = $c;
    }
    else {
        $next = $a;
    }

    if($c) {
        $previous = $c;
    }
    else if($b) {
        $previous = $b;
    }
    else {
        $previous = $a;
    }
}
if($cur = $b) {
    if($c) {
        $next = $c;
    }
    else if($a) {
        $next = $a;
    }
    else {
        $next = $b;
    }

    if($a) {
        $previous = $a;
    }
    else if($c) {
        $previous = $c;
    }
    else {
        $previous = $b;
    }
}
if($cur = $c) {
    if($a) {
        $next = $a;
    }
    else if($b) {
        $next = $b;
    }
    else {
        $next = $c;
    }

    if($b) {
        $previous = $b;
    }
    else if($a) {
        $previous = $a;
    }
    else {
        $previous = $c;
    }
}
```

Comment: $a, $b, $c are page names or true false variables? its not clear, and what is $curr? page name or boolean?

Comment: FYI, your code will yield incorrect results. `$cur = $a` assigns the value in `$a` to the value in `$cur`. You need to evaluate the expression `$cur == $a` or `$cur === $a` depending on your use case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UNTESTED**

```
$PRIVACY_PAGES[0] = "followers.php";
$PRIVACY_PAGES[1] = "following.php";
$PRIVACY_PAGES[2] = "friends.php";

function getNextPage($currPageName, $userPrivacy){
    //$userPrivacy is array of boolean same order as $PRIVACY_PAGES
    $currIdx = getPageIndex($currPageName);
    $loopStart = 0;

    if($currIdx > -1){
        $loopStart = $currIdx+1;
    }

    if($currIdx == 2){//he is on last page
        return "#";
    }

    for($v=$loopStart;$v<count($userPrivacy);$v++){
        if($userPrivacy[$v]==true){
            return $PRIVACY_PAGES[$v];
        }
    }//for loop

    return "#";//he have no permission to view any page further.
}

function getPageIndex($currentPageName){
    for($p=0;$p<count($PRIVACY_PAGES);p++){
        if($PRIVACY_PAGES[0] == $currentPageName)
            return $p;
    }//for loop
    return -1;//he is on another page, like index.php or gallery.php...
}
```

/////////////

```
//example :
$userPrivacy[0] = true;
$userPrivacy[1] = false;
$userPrivacy[2] = true;
$next = getNextPage("followers.php", $userPrivacy)
//$next should be friends.php

< html >
:
:
< a href="< ? php echo $next;?>">Next< /a >
```

Comment: getPrevPage() should be same concept just reverse the for loop, $v=count($userPrivacy);$v > $loopEnd;$v--

Answer (score 1):

an object orientated solution would be clean here, consider this pseudo code:

```
class page {

     private $nextpage;
     private $prevpage;
     private $permission;

     function __construct($nextpage, $permission)
     {
         $this->nextpage   = $nextpage;
         $this->permission = $permission;
     }

     public function GetNextPage($first = $this)
     {
          if ($this->nextpage == null || $first == $this) {
              return false;
          } elseif ($this->nextpage->isAllowed()) {
               return $this->nextpage;
          } else {
               return $this->nextpage->GetNextPage($first);
          }
     }

     public function isAllowed()
     {
         // Some authorization voodoo here
         return $_SESSION['userpermissions'] == $permission;
     }
}
```

Same code can be used for previous page. You could even make it dynamic in order to save you redundant code for next and previous.

Now all you have to do is inistantiate each page at the start of your application and you can easily browse through them.